# Android emulator is very very slow

Tags: android, android-emulator

My laptop: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU, 2GHz, 1GB RAM.

I created a target with SD Card 512MB, Device RAM size 512, snapshot enabled. **I waited for 30 minutes but the emulator doesn't ends up loading**. It keeps showing a flash word "Android" on the black screen.

Before running the emulator, I closed most other programs.

What's wrong with it? This is very frustrating. :(

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Comment: I always recommend foregoing the Emulator and rapidly testing on a real device if you can. Use the emulator for conformance testing to API's you do not have with you.

Comment: Android Emulator runs faster for me on Linux (Ubuntu 11.10) than on Windows 7. Far from perfect though, but much better.

Comment: I suggest you to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17394283/1204249

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't take more than 5-10min at most to build the emulator on initial startup.  The SD card size has no effect on memory usage, it's not loaded into memory, it just creates a larger image file for the sdcard.  Setting the emulator to have 256mb of ram will help, but in general when I have the same problem I just close down the emulator window and re-start it.  Sometimes it just gets hung-up on creation and isn't a memory issue (I have 16gb of ram and still have the problem from time to time)

Answer (score 3):

What is your CPU and RAM usage during startup? Do you have a lot of IO swapping occurring? Considering that Windows needs at least 512 to run right half of the time and Eclipse is a memory hog you probably just need more RAM.

Comment: CPU Usage now is 100%, PF Usage 1.73GB, I open Eclipse, Emulator and Firefox. 45 minutes passed.

Comment: Yeah, you're 73% over committed and the OS is trying to swap out all of the memory pages with pages on disk which is *extremely* slow.

Comment: Well, I have 16GB of RAM on my PC and giving >= 1GB to emulator crashes it. The best solution here is to use MIPS images I suppose. On my machine, loading of Android 4.2 MIPS image takes no longer than 2min. On the machine with 4GB of RAM it takes about 2-3min as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the emulated Android instance half of the physical memory on your machine. Get more memory.

Comment: And that's just for the SD card!

Comment: @dmon: Both the SD card and the device RAM are insane values. I usually use 32MB for the SD card, as it takes a while for the SD card image to be generated. However, that does not affect system RAM, as the SD card is just a file. The device RAM value has a far greater impact on the physical memory on the machine.

Comment: @CommonsWare: yep, I always start my emulators with 10 MB SDs. And you're right, for some reason I got confused and thought it mapped the SD straight to memory.

Answer (score 2):

Emulator is in general very slow, and the higher the OS version on the emulator, the slower it gets. I'm a game developer, and with my AMD Athlon X3 2.90 GHz with 4GB RAM it gives me 5-6 fps. I tried to open one of my apps on Honeycomb emulator, and it was really terrible. It opened, but I couldn't do anything with it. So the best answer is purchasing a real device.

Comment: I improved my RAM 2GB more (3GB now) and allocated 1024MB for "Device RAM size". It now ends up loading but it's still very slow, I think it is no longer the issue of RAM, is it related to graphics card?

Comment: I don't know how fast should be a PC to make emulator work at least fine, with no lags and slowdowns. Improving the computer will maybe give a bit more speed, but I'd prefer spending money on purchasing devices, at least a phone and a tablet.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same thing and in my case I had to set "Min SDK Version" when creating the project in Eclipse. Without this setting the emulator didn't start.

Comment: I just start the emulator, nothing to do with "Min SDK Version" or "project".

Comment: Right, but when you created the project did you specify "Min SDK Version"?

Answer (score 0):

Android Development Tools (ADT) 9.0.0 (or later) has a feature that allows you to save state of the AVD (emulator), and you can start your emulator instantly. You have to enable this feature while creating a new AVD or you can just create it later by editing the AVD.

Also I have increased the Device RAM Size to 1024 which results in a very fast emulator.

Refer the given below screenshots for more information.

[image]

[image]

And for speeding up your emulator you can refer to 
[Speed up your Android Emulator!:](http://jolicode.com/blog/speed-up-your-android-emulator)

Answer (score -1):

The native Android emulator is really slow. It's much faster if you use Android on a virtual machine. You can follow my detailed guide on setting it up. http://www.bobbychanblog.com/2011/07/faster-android-emulator-alternative-using-virtualbox/