# Android : 4.0.3 emulator closed automatically after some time

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am working on emulator 4.0.3, whenever runs the project new android emulator gets started, and previous emulator show blank screens i.e become idle with blank screen doesn't work anything. What will be the problem? How shall I solve it?

got error while resetting adb

```
[2012-05-11 16:54:11 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-05-11 16:54:11 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:395)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:397)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:102)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[2012-05-11 16:54:12 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

The emulator image shown below..

[image: Valid XHTML].

and it is very slow.. when I tried to increase device ram size from 512 to 1024 in emulator it doesn't worked for me. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: try to reset the adb in eclipse. It should display the emulator on the DDMS.

Comment: when I dont work on emulator for 10mins.. its goes idle with blank screen..

Comment: Try creating another emulator with a different configuration. Check if this happens on all emulator instances. If so, you might want to update / reinstall your avd manager. Also, try running your SDK Manager directly from the SDK folder, and not from the Eclipse, that might help resolve the issue

Comment: updated -- while resetting thr adb

Comment: @SamSPICA --- k i ll try with diff config.. thanks..

Comment: same problem.... after some time screen becomes idle.. cant work anything..

Comment: If your device ram capacity is low. try decreasing the avd ram to 256 mb.

Comment: @user892500 --  thanks .. my ram capacity is 2GB.

Comment: Is it possible to attach a screenshot of the "idle" screen? That might help us identify the problem.

Comment: @SamSPICA -- i have upadted with image.. please say me any solution..

Comment: Check out this answer: [Android emulator is very very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6281954/713354)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wipe the sdcard... & kill the adb process in task manager and restart it again, restart eclipse as well than try, it will

Answer (score 3):

Android 4.0.3 emulator has few bugs and also with the logcat. Its better you create a fresh emulator and restart the adb. I hope this may help

Answer (score 2):

I was having same problem. I have just restarted i.e re-started Eclipse and recreated Android SDK.

It works fine for me. Hope it'll help for you too.