# Android Emulator Still very slow after installing EFI Firmware, updating OSX, Updated Android SDK Tools

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

My mac details are:

[image]

Installed Mac Pro EFI Firmware and also Updated OSX as suggested here to enable virtualization(http://kb.parallels.com/en/5653)

Updated Android SDK Tools as suggested in following message:

> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. Your emulator is
>   out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
>    - Start Android Studio
>    - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
>    - Click "SDK Tools" tab
>    - Check "Android SDK Tools" checkbox
>    - Click "OK"

But when I run

```
emulator @Nexus_5X_API_23 -no-boot-anim -qemu
```

I still get this:

> emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
>
> Hax is enabled
>
> Hax ram_size 0x60000000
>
> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

PS: I have already read this [Android emulator is very very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278962/android-emulator-is-very-very-slow)
and 
[How to enable support of CPU virtualization on Macbook Pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580491/how-to-enable-support-of-cpu-virtualization-on-macbook-pro)

Comment: Are you sure your emulated system is in fact an Intel one? If you are emulating ARM-based Android you'll take aperformance hit. RAM usage may also have an impact (and the speed of the disk changes how large that impact is)

Comment: The emulator typically takes up 2GB of RAM for itself, so you are left with another 2GB. Not too nice, running a browser or something else that uses up a lot of memory will be a bad idea

Comment: @paul-stelian How to be sure ?

Comment: So what do you suggest for 4GM Machine? I used to use GenyMotion when it used to be free it used to work perfectly fine on 4GB RAM.

Comment: Perhaps configure your current emulator to give something like 1GB instead of 2? Or not running many other apps at the same time as the emulator (the browser is a particularly bad one to run)

Comment: removing the option `-qemu` speeded up the emulator quite a lot, not sure why, i was under the impression opposite should happen.

Comment: Oh I see I believe that actually is useful on Linux (where Qemu would use KVM for its acceleration), and on Macs simply uses an emulator. Nice!